# Let $(a_n), (b_n),$ be bounded, then prove that $c_n$ converges and give its value.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Could I get some feedback on the following proof, I feel becoming a good mathematician is through constant feedback and improvement of your work, I tried to make it short, but well-readable.

> We are given that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are bounded sequences, and also:
>   $$ (n-1)a_n \leq n^2 c_n \leq (n+1)b_n$$
>   Prove that $c_n$ converges and give the value of the limit.

First of all, we know that these sequences are bounded, so surely we have that:
$$L \geq a_n \land b_n \leq U$$
For some lower bound $L$ and some upper bound $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
We now apply this: 
$$ (n-1) L \leq (n-1)a_n \leq n^2 c_n \leq (n+1)b_n \leq  (n+1)U$$
$$ \frac{L}{n}-\frac{L}{n^2}=\frac{(n-1) L}{n^2}  \leq  c_n\leq \frac{(n+1) U}{n^2} =\frac{U}{n}+\frac{U}{n^2}$$
Both these sequence converge to zero, so we have that in the limit:
$$0 \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c_n \leq 0$$
By the squeeze theorem we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c_n =0$

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely fine proof. You may want to find if the given condition can be relaxed. For example, if $n^2$ is replaced by $n^\alpha$ in the above proof, which values would work? $n = n^1$ would not work : try to find a counterexample.

Comment: Nice variation on the problem :)

Comment: You are welcome!